# Use references to some elements of a std::vector, or the position of such elements in the vector, to iterate over them

Tags: c++, vector, reference, set, std

In an application I am writing, I store my data in objects such as

```
std::vector<my_struct> db;
```

and often I need to refer to some of their elements and use an std::set in which I store their positions in the vector (which won't change)

```
std::set<int> elements_i_like;
```

Then, I access db elements with

```
for ( auto it = elements_i_like.begin(); it!=elements_i_like.end(); it++){
    db[*it].do_something();
}
```

I have a doubt though, would it be better, performance-wise, not to store the indices of the elements in the vector, but a direct reference to them?

```
std::vector<my_struct> db; //where i store the data (edit form original question)
std::set<my_struct&> elements_i_like;//reference to the specific structs, stored in the vector, that i want to iterate on
```

and do

```
for( auto it= elements_i_like.begin(); it!=elements_i_like.end(); it++){
    (*it).do_something();
}
```

And could there be any drawbacks in doing so?
Thanks.

Comment: One drawback is that you can't store references in a container...

Comment: But you *can* store `std::reference_wrapper`s.

Comment: In my opinion vectors are quite "hungry" in terms of performance in pre C++11 code, remember that a vector is a chunk of data that is granted to be contiguos in memory ( like a plain old array ), sometimes when you add an element to the vector the whole vector needs to be relocated, and the more the vector grows the higher the chances are that you are paying a good cost in terms of memory operations. All depends on what you mean with "performance".

Comment: @user2485710: From the OP's question, it sounds like the vector/set combo is a given.  (Note also that vector insertion is O(1) amortized.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth if the point is "the performance" yes and no, it depends, I personally think that finding the right data structure it's more important than picking one between references, pointers and iterators ...

Comment: @user2485710 actually the performance of vector is quite astonishing, if you watch [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style) you'll come across some data by stroustrup himself namely [this graph](http://bulldozer00.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/vector-list-perf.png?w=595)

Comment: @Borgleader that is probably C++11 related ...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth if the Vector is really O(1) you should explain who pays the price for the relocation and the memory management.

Comment: @user2485710 If I understand correctly, OP is asking read from vector instead of write.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thank you! By the way, I've been a bit imprecise. I want to store my data in the vector, and put references to the elements i want to iterate on in the set. Can this be possible? -gonna edit my question

Comment: @user2485710: On average, the memory for each element in a vector is only reallocated once (assuming you're only adding).  That's pretty cheap, especially considering the other benefits (zero memory overhead, contiguous storage, O(1) lookup, etc.)

Comment: @user2485710 Thank you! Yes I am reading from the vector. And I am using c++11.

Comment: Are you adding further elements after storing the indices/references in the set? If you add further elements, the references may be invalidated (whereas indices are not).

Comment: @jogojapan Ah, thanks! That solves my doubts... because I am adding further elements. So i will use the indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store references in a container and in any case, even if the compiler/language allowed it, you will still need two dereferences to evaluate each iteration.

By the way, if C++11 is available, you could rewrite the loop as:

```
for(auto& elem : elements_i_like)
    elem.do_something();
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems a great solution. I just wonder: how should I declare elements_i_like?

Comment: ok, i figured out how to use this in range for loops. In the end, i think int will be the best choice for my original question, mostly because of what jogojapan said.